# Trying to run Gulp on Mac but it's not working

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to run Gulp on my Mac. I went into terminal and cd'd into my gulp folder. When I type

```
gulp
```

I get "-bash: gulp: command not found". In my gulp folder I do have a gulpfile.js in there but again I get nothing. Where do I go from here?

Here's the errors I get when I `npm install -g`:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:gulp-dev damien$ npm install -g gulp
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v7.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/gulp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/damien/.npm/_logs/2017-04-11T20_42_46_317Z-debug.log
MacBook-Pro-2:gulp-dev damien$ npm install -g gulp
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v7.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/gulp'
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/bin/gulp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/damien/.npm/_logs/2017-04-11T20_43_48_551Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed Gulp on your machine yet?

If your folder has a `package.json` file, make sure you can see Gulp in there listed between your `devDependencies`. These dependencies are what you use during development of your Node project.

If you don't have a `package.json` file, you can create one in the command line via `npm init`, then install Gulp locally on your machine with `npm install -g gulp`, and then install the command line interface for gulp in your project folder: `npm install --save-dev gulp-cli`. The CLI will run the Gulp executable with the `Gulpfile.js` that's in your project.

More information can be found on their website: http://gulpjs.com/

Comment: I do have a package.json file. i never installed gulp, i don't think, but i just ran your command npm install -g gulp and i get a bunch of errors. I'll edit my question to show the errors

Comment: Also, I tried setting permissions on the parent folder for all access but that did not work

Comment: Yes it seems that you don't have permissions to do so. That means you'll have to use `sudo` with the `npm` commands but that's generally ill-advised.

 Multiple people wrote about a safe way to do so:
- https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

- https://johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/

- http://www.competa.com/blog/how-to-run-npm-without-sudo/

Comment: That worked! I did sudo anyway and looks like it went through. Typed gulp afterwards and it was trying to do something but I received an error anyway. I'll open up a new ticket for that. Thanks!